# Unexpected String Concatenation with + + in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string, string-concatenation

Today, I found an unexpected behaviour of JavaScript while I was using the `+` operator :

```
"a" + "" //returns "a"
"a" + + "" //returns "a0"
```

Why does the second expression yield `"a0"`?

Comment: In `"a" + + ""`, `+ ""` is considered as `+("")` which is evaluated as `0`. In simple terms, first `+` is used to concat operator and second is used as unary operator on `""`

Comment: Obligatory link :P https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat (you are not alone)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `+` symbol is used for multiple operators and operations:

- `a + b` where `a` or `b` is a string performs concatenation. If the other value is not a string it is converted to one.
- `a + b` where `a` and `b` are numbers performs addition.
- `++a` or `a++` performs incrementation (increase by one).
- `+ a` which is the unary positive operator, which takes a number and returns it unchanged. This is sometimes used by programmers as a shortcut to convert a string to a number.

JavaScript automatically converts types when one of these operations is encountered with other or mixed data types. Objects and arrays tend to convert to strings automatically, and concatenation has priority over addition. This is why `number + object` returns a string, which might not make sense at first if you expected `+` to represent addition.

In conclusion, the interpreter guesses the operation based on its context. If you write `"a" + + ""`, it sees two `+` operators in a row. Since these can't both be binary operators, it understands that the second `+` is the unary `+`, which converts a string to a number. The empty string automatically converts to `0` because the unary `+` only works with numbers, and then the other `+` sees a string and a number. Since there's a string, it converts the other operand to a string and performs concatenation.

Answer (score 1):

This is the same as `"a" + (+ "")`

`+ ""` casts the empty string to number and will return `0` for empty string. 
Similarly `+"22"` returns number `22`

So now you have `"a" + 0`

String concatenated with number returns string and you end up with `'a0'`

Answer (score 0):

In your second line, that's a coercion to a number using the `+` operator.

So actually `+""` is converting "" to a number (->0) and then it concatenates the result to the string "a".

So the resulting string will be: "a0".

Answer (score 0):

Along with being the concatenation and addition operator, the `+` operator is also a unary operator (i.e. an operator which operates on a single operand). When used as an unary operator like `+value`, JavaScript casts (converts) operand's value to Number type.  For Example :

```
+"4" // returns 4
+"42" // returns 42
+"Hello" // returns NaN (Not A Number), i.e. the String could not be converted into Number
+"" //returns 0; special case
```

So, your expression `"a" + + ""` is evaluated like `"a"+0` ( returns `"a0"`).

Remove the whitespaces and it won't work and throw an error.